# Django adding hour and minute from form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

It is possible to add hour, minute and second from admin dashboard, but now I want to add it to my template.

`models.py`:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateDocumentForm(ModelForm):
...
    class Meta:
        model = ComplaintDocument
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'date': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SplitDateTimeWidget` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget